# Using sql lite database in another android app

Tags: java, android, sqlite

hello i have a problem with android. In my app i get data from a webservice  and i read it into a sql lite database . In my activity i have multiple spinners who are filled with data from the DB. After selecting all the spinners and clicking the button i go to an other activty where i click a link and the data is written into another table.

I will explain what the  app is like a form where a student can choose with school , study area,.. till you have the tuition you want. You can subscribe than for the course(that data is written to another table).

In the other app you can see the tuition whit the number of subscribers.

the first app works but my problem is that i need the table of subscibers used in app 1 for app2 
i have read about COntent providers ,shared user id but none of it works.

Can somebody help me?

```
 public class SchemaHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final static String DATABASE_NAAM ="av_helpdesk.be.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSIE = 10;

public SchemaHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAAM, null, DATABASE_VERSIE);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
            + GegevensTabel.TABEL_NAAM
            + " (" + GegevensTabel.ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + GegevensTabel.INSTELLING
            + " TEXT,"

            + GegevensTabel.OPLEIDINGSTYPE
            + " TEXT,"
            + GegevensTabel.OPLEIDINGSGEBIED
            + " TEXT,"+ GegevensTabel.OPLEIDING+" TEXT,"
           + GegevensTabel.MODULE+" TEXT,"
           +  GegevensTabel.LESPLAATS_ADRES+" TEXT,"
            + GegevensTabel.AAVANGS_DATUM+" TEXT"+");"
    );

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
            + InschrijvingTabel.TABEL_NAAM
            + " (" + InschrijvingTabel.ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + InschrijvingTabel.LESPLAATS
            + " TEXT, "
            + InschrijvingTabel.OPLEIDING
            + " TEXT, "
            + InschrijvingTabel.Module
            + " TEXT, "+ InschrijvingTabel.AANTAL+" INTEGER"+");"

    );


}


 public interface InschrijvingTabel {

    String ID="_id";
    String Module = "_module";
    String TABEL_NAAM = "TBL_INSCHRIJVING1";
    String AANTAL="_aantal";
    String OPLEIDING="_opleiding";
    String LESPLAATS="_lesplaats";
}

    public class InschrijvingDB extends  SchemaHelper {
    public InschrijvingDB(Context context) {
        super(context);



    }



    public void  adVakken()
    {

        SQLiteDatabase sd=getWritableDatabase();
      //  String xx=x.getModule();
    // sd.rawQuery("insert into "+InschrijvingTabel.TABEL_NAAM+"("+ InschrijvingTabel.Module+") values("+xx+")",null);
   //  sd.rawQuery("insert into "+InschrijvingTabel.TABEL_NAAM+"(_module) values('cc')",null);



    }


public class contentPV extends ContentProvider {
    static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.example.derae.lessenrooster.databank.contentPV";
    static final String URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/*";
    static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL);
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        Context context = getContext();
InschrijvingDB x= new InschrijvingDB(context);
    return false;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: All your ContentProvider methods return default values. You have to actually implement them for it to work

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 1 database that has all the tables you want to use and you're logging in to that database from app 2, then you should be able to access every table there.

Try debugging techniques to see what's going wrong with app 2, like print debugging.

If you can connect to your database normally from app2, then check if there's anything wrong with your Queries to get data from the desired table. Break your problem down into parts.

-I'm sorry if this is not helpful enough, I'm no expert myself, but I hope my tips help you discover the problem yourself.